# holomorphic map between compact Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-geometry

Why nonconstant holomorphic map between compact riemann surfaces is surjection? I don't understand: if open-closed connected subset X of connected space Y, then X is all Y??

Comment: This is not research-level. The image $f(X)$ of a compact open set $X$ (such as the original Riemann surface) under a non-constant holomorphic map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ must be compact and open, therefore clopen. So the complement $Y - f(X)$ must also be open (compact sets are closed in Hausdorff spaces), so $Y$ is disconnected by definition. Contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that nonconstant holomorphic maps are open (any open set of a compact Riemann surface is a union of open sets that are each holomorphically equivalent to an open disc in the complex plane; then use the [open mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) and the fact that taking images under a function preserves unions), and that continuous maps from a compact space to a Hausdorff space are closed. Hence the image $f(X)$ is both open and closed in $Y$. If your definition of compact Riemann surface includes connectedness, then the image must be all of $Y$.

Comment: Dear user: an open annulus is not holomorphically equivalent to an open disc!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal But an open annulus is a *union* of open discs. (Perhaps the English threw you off?)

Comment: Oops! I simply misread. Your answer is fine (and so is my English, I think...)